# Как правильно перенести формулу в код С++

Tags: c++, математика

Я попробовала єто но оно показивает ошибку:

```latex
h=\sqrt{a^2-\left(\frac{\left(d-b\right)^2+a^2-c^2}{2\left(d-b\right)}\right)^2}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нужно показывать то, что попробовали

Comment: Не понял, вы пробовали С++ или TeX?...

Comment: Вставки формулы в виде PNG с прозрачностью с диагональным зелеными полосами - это какое-то издевательство, особенно для просмотра с темной темой сайта. Перегенерил на основе кода.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Поэтапно расписал, шаг за шагом:

```
double h = 
double h = sqrt()
double h = sqrt(pow(c, 2) - )
double h = sqrt(pow(c, 2) - pow(() / (), 2))
double h = sqrt(pow(c, 2) - pow((pow((a - b), 2) + pow(c, 2) - pow(d, 2)) / (), 2))
double h = sqrt(pow(c, 2) - pow((pow((a - b), 2) + pow(c, 2) - pow(d, 2)) / (2 * (a - b)), 2)) // result
```

Comment: Опечатка `poww`?

Comment: @Kromster, да, писал через Ctrl + C / Ctrl + V часть строк

Comment: @Kromster, уже поменял

Answer (score -3):

Во-первых, что за суперхитрость экранировать слешем начальную букву имени функции? Во-вторых, за именем функции должен следовать параметр в скобках, а не блок операторов. В-втретьих, а ксор там нафига?

```
h=sqrt(c*c-((a-b)*(a-b)+c*c-d*d)/(2.0*(a-b))*((a-b)*(a-b)+c*c-d*d)/(2.0*(a-b)));
```

Comment: если вы не понимаете вопрос, то сначала желательно поучится самому. Это язык представления сложных текстов и формул [LaTeX](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX)

Comment: Открою тебе страшную тайну: вопрос вполне так можно понимать. Так вот, он не про латекс спрашивал.